# Spring web service outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Here is a requirement where i want to mention explicitly that to communicate with other outside system use TLSV1.2 and not the default TLSV1.0
How i could override or implement this requirement

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="someID"
request-channel="clientRequest" reply-channel="clientReply"
uri="some.com" reply-timeout="1000" marshaller="clientMarshaller" 
unmarshaller="clientMarshaller" message-sender="messageSender" >
</int-ws:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are on the Java 7 and seems for me this should help you:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

More info, please [here](http://fsanglier.blogspot.com/2015/04/java-7-and-tlsv12-supported-but-not-enabled.html).